# Bash how to execute all commands but return exit value of previous command

Tags: bash, command-line, pipe, return-value, logical-operators

I want to test if a c++ library was successfully installed so I have a chain of commands:

```
$ echo '#include "library_to_check_for"' > test.cpp && g++ test.cpp ??? rm test.cpp ???
```

Where the remove command needs to happen every time but I need $? to return the status from the compile command (i.e. compilation was successful & the library was found, or not)

Logically, I think there's a way to AND/OR something in there to get it to work.. I just can't wrap my head around it

possibly this..?

```
$ echo '#include "library_to_check_for"' > test.cpp; g++ test.cpp; rm test.cpp; exit (something?)
```

Comment: Check out the `trap` BASH builtin. Run the whole thing in a subshell as well, that way you could use `set -e` to make it even clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could store the return value in a variable, like so?

```
echo '#include "library_to_check_for"' > test.cpp; g++ test.cpp; LASTRETURN=$?; rm test.cpp;
echo $LASTRETURN
```